# Define boundaries or constraints for scipy optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize

I am confused about boundaries and constaints in `scipy.optimize`

```
def objective(x):
    y = x*x - 40*x
    return y

def constraint1(x):
    x < 500
    return x

# initial guesses
n = 1
x0 = np.zeros(n)
x0[0] = 10

# show initial objective
print('Initial Objective: ' + str(objective(x0)))

# optimize
b = (1.0,500.0)
# b = (None,None)
bnds = (b)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons = ([con1])
solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',\
                bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

How do I set that the `x` can only be certain values for example `x = [10,36,258,500]`?

Comment: You can't. That would be a discrete-optimization problem and scipy.minimize is build around the concept of continuous-optimization, local-optima and differentiability (with one solver being less strict about the latter).

Comment: I see thanks. Any recommendations for python libraries on discrete optimization?

Comment: [pySCIPOpt](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt) might be a good start.